# Phase change by a capacitor for an electric motor

Tags: ltspice

I built a circuit that simulates a 220 volt AC 50 Hz power source.
I connected a 1.5mF capacitor in the column, and a 100 ohm load.
Why don't I see a phase change on the oscilloscope?
(When I lower the capacitor value there is a change in phase but the voltage drops).[image]

Comment: \$i = \frac{V}{R-\frac{j}{\omega C}}\$, \$\varphi=arctg\frac{R}{\omega C}\$

Comment: `there's a change of phase but the voltage drops` - yes, you would expect the voltage to drop by sqrt(2) when the phase change is 45 degrees, for the first order filter you've shown

Comment: If a motor is designed to use a capacitor, it's designed to be OK with the reduced voltage. If indeed the voltage reduces, as a motor is inductive, and there could be a resonant rise.

Answer (score 7):

The phase change is there but it is very small so you can't see it.

The RC circuit has a time constant of 150ms and mains frequency has period of 20ms. In other words, the RC highpass filter has cutoff of 1 Hz, which is much lower than 50 Hz, so it will pass 50 Hz with almost no effect.

And you have a simulator for 155VAC, not 220VAC.

Comment: Is it like that in reality? (In the blower of an air conditioner?).
I mean, if I plug in an oscilloscope, will I see this thing?

Comment: @נירברוך Only if the blower is a 100 ohm resistor, you will see the exact same thing on scope screen. But, the blower is not a 100 ohm resistor so no, you won't see what you simulated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, notice that the input current is given by:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right|\cdot\exp\left(\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right)
\text{j}\right)\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\frac{\displaystyle\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}\tag2$$

And:

$$\arg\left(\frac{\displaystyle\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)-\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)\right)\tag3$$

So, when looking at your case we get:

$$\text{I}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\frac{33\pi}{\sqrt{1+225\pi^2}}\cdot\cos\left(100\pi t-\arctan\left(15\pi\right)\right)\tag4$$